# checkbox in rails view updating database value without Javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am trying to make the following:
Any solution to update the database with the value and with the checkbox without using JavaScript with a click on or click off?

```
<%= form_for :act_as do |f| %>
<%= f.check_box(:suspend_flag, { checked: (ActAs.find_by(ModifiedID:@misc_data[:user]).SuspendFlag ? false :true), class: 'abcd' }, 0, 1) %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Uhm...can you explain a bit more clearly what you'd like to achieve? The database value gets persisted once you click `submit` - or you need to update the database value before even clicking on `submit`?

Comment: The ideal would be if I can update the database just on clicking the box, without submit and is updating the database, but if there is no solution for this with only rails, I would be happy with the sumbit button, too.